# averaging time series data in r xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have time series data where the values are stored at the end of a 1-min sampling interval (i.e. data for 00:00 belongs to the interval 23:59 - 00:00 etc.).

I now would like to average in 5 min intervals giving the mean concentrations at 00:05, 00:10, etc.

What I get with the code below is the averages at 00:04, 00:09, etc., which seems to be related to the endpoints function, but I cannot figure out how to average correctly (i.e. in my case minutes 00:01 to 00:05 reported as mean at 00:05 etc.)

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

t1 <- as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:1:0") 
t2 <- as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:15:0") 
d <- seq(t1, t2, by = "1 min") 
x <- rnorm(length(d)) 

z <- zoo(x, d) 

period.apply(z,endpoints(z,"mins",5),mean)

> 2012-01-01 00:04:00 2012-01-01 00:09:00 2012-01-01 00:14:00 2012-01-01 00:15:00 
      0.6864088          -0.9403631          -0.4269895           0.6728044
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `endpoints` function is working correctly. You need to change your index values. `00:05:00` is the *beginning* of the 5th minute, not the end.

```
> z <- zoo(x, d-1)
> period.apply(z,endpoints(z,"mins",5),mean)
2012-01-01 00:04:59 2012-01-01 00:09:59 2012-01-01 00:14:59 
          1.2324436          -0.5881076           0.5067009
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see. And how would I round the index to the next minute (sorry, I'm new to this time series thing)? I am actually transforming the output back to a data.frame and need the 5 min resolution.

Comment: @user3460194: you can use `align.time` to round to the next `n`th second (so `n=5*60` in your 5-minute case).